# How to correctly use pre populated Realm database in Android?

Tags: android, realm

I'm on Realm 0.90.0 and I'm having problems with loading a pre populated Realm db: once I load the file from the source, `isEmpty` on the returned collection gives true, when it obviously isn't (I created it by importing a csv in Realm Browser and everything seems fine when opening the db in there).

This is what I did so far:

- I put a realm db file in my `res/raw` folder
- I loaded it in `MyApplication` class by doing

  ```
  copyBundledRealmFile(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.station), Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME); // more info about this is said later
  RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                  .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                  .build();
  Realm.deleteRealm(config);
  Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
  ```
- Then in my Fragment's `onViewCreated` I queried for every object in it

  ```
  Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
  RealmResults<Station4Database> stations = realm.where(Station4Database.class).findAll();
  Log.d("TAG", "stations loading ended", 
        stations.isLoaded(),// true
        stations.isValid(), // true
        stations.isEmpty(), // true instead of FALSE
        stations.size());   // 0 instead of 2929 (actual size)
  ```

Why doesn't it get the objects right? Any help / input would be immensely appreciated!

Thanks!

PS this is the function I took from the official example in Realm's repo (should make the job right).

```
private String copyBundledRealmFile(InputStream inputStream, String outFileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), outFileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Because you create your Realm then delete it with `Realm.deleteRealm(config);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it!

The problem was that I was using a non-perfectly-mapped version of the model class for the objects in the database (`Station4Database` in this specific case, the field names were not exactly the same!).

Therefore, remember kids, always use the model definitions generated by Realm Browser if you don't wanna incur in Realm retrieving empty collections without giving any kind of error / exception back to you.